# Loops through Array executes "else" even when "if" statement is true (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, if-statement

Simple question.. Not sure why this is happening...

Question: the "**else**" runs even when the **if** statement is true..

In this case...

---

The City entered is "Los Angelos" which is an array element of var "theAnswers"
Meaning the alert should run and the program should finish...

What happens instead..

---

The program displays the else alert.. then displays the proper alert(if).
See for yourself...

```
var theAnswers = ["New York City", "Chicago", "Los Angelos", "Cleveland", "Ohio", "Seattle", "Boston", "Miami", "Philadelphia"];

var userAnswer = prompt("I am thinking of a Major City.. guess which one it is?", "Los Angelos");
userAnswer = userAnswer.toLowerCase();

for (var i = 0; i < theAnswers.length; i++) {
    if (userAnswer === theAnswers[i].toLowerCase()) {
        alert("Good, your guess is correct. You get one point!");
        break;
    }

    else{
        alert("Hmm... not quite the City I was looking for... Better luck next time!");

    }
}
```

Comment: can you create fiddle for the same

Comment: you can use in array indexoff

Comment: @exexzian sure can.. excuse me for not doing so earlier. I thought you could run it directly from SO.

https://jsfiddle.net/6rctjxot/#&togetherjs=cBb3GxLTAP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because you are showing the message in the `else` for each check that you make. It will show the message for each city that doesn't match. Look through all the cities first, then show the result once:

```
var found = false;
for (var i = 0; i < theAnswers.length; i++) {
    if (userAnswer === theAnswers[i].toLowerCase()) {
        found = true;
        break;
    }
}
if (found) {
    alert("Good, your guess is correct. You get one point!");
}else{
    alert("Hmm... not quite the City I was looking for... Better luck next time!");
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This worked well.
The issue i was having with the boolean was nesting it improperly when I attempted to use one.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the for loop. You don't have to loop through the array to know if answer exist in it , Just know the position of it will suffice. Try this:

```
var theAnswers = ["New York City", "Chicago", "Los Angelos", "Cleveland", "Ohio", "Seattle", "Boston", "Miami", "Philadelphia"];
var userAnswer = prompt("I am thinking of a Major City.. guess which one it is?", "Los Angelos");

if (theAnswers.indexOf(userAnswer)>=0) {
    alert("Good, your guess is correct. You get one point!");
}else{
    alert("Hmm... not quite the City I was looking for... Better luck next time!");
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pxwvbunt/)

Comment: `indexOf` would return `0` for `New York City`. You need to use `>=0` for the test. Also the original code checks for a lowercase version.

Comment: Thank you for this one! I wondered how I could search all the elements without looping... this is it.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't actually execute the "else" when the condition is true.

```
if (userAnswer === theAnswers[i].toLowerCase())
```

The first time this condition is evaluated, i is 0, so theAnswers[i] is "New York City".